# Mongoose not enforcing type specified in schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose "Costs" object created that saves successfully to a Mongo collection.  In the Mongoose schema for the Costs object, I specify types for each of the columns:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var crypto = require('crypto');

var CostsSchema = new Schema({

    property_hash:String,

    month: Number,

    year: Number,

    spend: Number,

    updated_by: String,

    channel: String,

    source: String,

    updated: Date
});

mongoose.model('Costs', CostsSchema);
```

But when I call Costs.collection.insert() passing an array of objects with all the properties set as strings, They get saved to Mongo without error.

Sample invalid object that gets saved successfully:

```
{ channel: "websites",
month: "I should be an integer",
property_hash: "1234566",
source: "trade",
spend: "I am an invalid integer",
updated: "I am an invalid date",
updated_by: "fred",
year: "Invalid year" }
```

Comment: You need to validate your insert before running the insert command. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#collection_Collection-insert) you can see that this is not a method implemented in Mongoose, but rather in MongoDB driver, so validation does not happen at all - documents are directly saved to Mongo.

For your need, you'd better use [#insertMany](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany) method.

Comment: even if you use the Mongoose method you still might fall - If you have in the schema a type String property and you try to save a Number into it it will not fail, it will cast it into a String (might not be what you expect or wish).
Take a look at this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464220/is-it-possible-to-disable-automatic-type-casting-for-mongoose-schematypes