# Is it possible to disable automatic type casting for Mongoose SchemaTypes?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose, schema

For a model with this Schema...

`{
  name: { type: String }
}`

...the following automatically casts the provided value to a string instead of enforcing the type:

`document.name = 2;
document.validate(err => {
  // Err is null, document.name === '2'
})`

Is there a simple way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: I think that it not posible, check this [post](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4745)

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this with a [custom string type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/customschematypes.html) that overrides the default casting behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this, it looks like mongoose will be supporting this according to [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7045).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lean()` method with your find/findOne queries.
`lean()` will remove all the effect a mongoose schema has, i.e. it will return data as it is saved in MongoDB without any typecasting.

**Note:-** After using `lean()` you will not be able to call update or save on that returned data.
Also, this will increase your query performance.

example

```
Model.find().lean().exec((err, result) => {
    console.log(result);    //data without any typecasting
    /*some operations on result*/
    result.save(); // this will not work  
});
```