# How to apply mongoose middleware pre on findOneAndUpdate method to validate type of data?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, middleware, mongoose-schema

When I try to update or findOneAndUpdate it only validates wether any required are missing, but it doesn´t validate the data type. At the moment I can update the name property to a number and no validation error happens. Any idea on what to do?

```
mongoose.set('runValidators', true);
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema ({
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  morada: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User
```

```
const update = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let post = await Post.findOneAndUpdate(req.params, req.body, {new: true});     
    res.json(post)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json(e)
  }
}
```

As I have read [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) I could use the pre middleware to validate data type, but I´m having trouble with how to use it to update:

```
Post.pre("save", function(next, done) {
    let self = this;

    if (invalid) {  // This is where I think I should validate the data type, but don´t know how to
        // Throw an Error
        self.invalidate("nome", "name must be a string");
        next(new Error("nome must be a string"));
    }

    next();
});
```

Any suggestions? Thanks on advance

Comment: This is caused by mongoose automatic casting. see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464220/is-it-possible-to-disable-automatic-type-casting-for-mongoose-schematypes)

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is but if I were you, 1) I would place `pre` code block inside UserSchema file right above `const User =...` 2) Then I would start pre code block with `UserSchema.pre("updateOne",....`